# MATLAB planes to solid

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to convert a .dat file of planes into 3d solids in MATLAB. The .dat file contains several hundred non-intersecting planes in a grid format x1, x2, y1, y2, A, B, C where A, B, and C are the coefficients in the plane equation. I eventually would like to export it as an stl file. Any ideas how I might go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you have 2 sets of x & y without any z?